# Spring Boot + Maven: repositoryFactoryBean not found

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, datatables

I'm using [https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables] to work with [datatables.net](https://datatables.net) js library. Specifically I require Spring Boot to create a

```
public interface ProjectsRepository extends QDataTablesRepository<Project,Long> { }
```

to do so, I have annotated my main class with the corresponding repository bean.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = QDataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class WebApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApp.class, args);
    }
```

This results in

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'apiTaskRenameController' defined in file [D:\dev\adwords-api-tools\fawo\target\classes\com\company\ApiTaskRenameController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.mapping.DataTablesOutput org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.qrepository.QDataTablesRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.mapping.DataTablesInput,com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,java.util.function.Function)! No property findAll found for type Project!
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'projectsRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.mapping.DataTablesOutput org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.qrepository.QDataTablesRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.mapping.DataTablesInput,com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,java.util.function.Function)! No property findAll found for type Project!
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.mapping.DataTablesOutput org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.qrepository.QDataTablesRepository.findAll(org.springframework.data.jpa.datatables.mapping.DataTablesInput,com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,com.querydsl.core.types.Predicate,java.util.function.Function)! No property findAll found for type Project!
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findAll found for type Project!
```

Curiously this error doesn't arise when starting the application with IntelliJ using this configuration. The same error does occur in IntelliJ as well, when the `repositoryFactoryBeanClass` is not specified. I suspect that Maven for some reason cannot locate this factory class.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Supplied pom.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>api_tools</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>project_name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.9-SNAPSHOT-1</version>

<properties>
    <docker.image.prefix>docker-registry.dev.finnwaa.local</docker.image.prefix>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

    <!--Disambiguations-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Databases-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring Modules-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-ldap</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.14.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--Other Utilities-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.paradoxical</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.3-experimental-1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.darrachequesne</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa-datatables</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>4.2.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ttf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>woff2</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                <buildArgs>
                    <FAWO_TAG>${project.version}</FAWO_TAG>
                </buildArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.603</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: How does your pom.xml looks like?

Comment: Sorry. Added pom file

Comment: This is strange, I guess Spring/Java should complain in another way if there was a classpath problem. But who knows... How exactly do you launch the app from cmd line? Looks like you rely on the `spring-boot:repackage` here? Can you see some differences in the final Java commands launched from IDEA vs from cmd line? And did you try to increase logging level, e. g. from Spring?

Comment: It would be better to push a minimal reproducible example on some public repo. e.g. in the above code `ApiTaskRenameController` is also missing.

Answer (score 1):

Change basePackages attribute so that it points to ProjectsRepository package.

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = QDataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean.class, basePackages = "to.package.path.to.ProjectsRepository")
```

Comment: It works, for someone using Datatable JPA Data with Spring Boot, you must add annotation above to Application class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you killed the default `JpaRepositoryFactoryBean` in order to use `QDataTablesRepositoryFactoryBean`. From the exception the first bean that was not found was `projectsRepository`, and I'm guessing this repository is a JPA Repository.

You need to configure your `@EnableJpaRepositories` in a way that it don't deactivate JpaRepositoryFactoryBean. If you look at the `repositoryFactoryBeanClass` default value you will see the following:

```java
Class<?> repositoryFactoryBeanClass() default JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.class;
```

Take a look at [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-componentscan-filter-type) to find some alternative ways to configure that annotation.